# Function returns undefined, but variable not undefined in scope of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, httprequest, undefined

I have a very simple function here trying to grab a post from r/askreddit.

```js
const simple_get = require('simple-get');

function get_post() {
  simple_get('https://reddit.com/r/askreddit/random.json', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    let body = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      var post = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval('(' + body + ')')))
      console.log(post);
      return post;
    });
  });
}

console.log(get_post());
```

The function returns undefined. However, when `post` is outputted on line 17 (inside the function), it returns the correct object. Here are some logs:

> undefined.....reddit.js:23
>
> Array(2) [Object, Object].....reddit.js:17

Alongside simply returning `post`, I have tried making a global variable and setting that to `post`. That also didn't work. I need it as a function so I can set it in a while loop to do things like get a new post if it's a mod post, so alternatives to that would also be appreciated.

Node version 10.15.0 with simple-get 3.1.0 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Three issues because `simple_get()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  1) It's timing.  `res.on('end', ...)` happens long AFTER your function returns.  2) You don't actually have any return value from `get_post()`.  Your `return` is inside a callback, not from `get_post()`.  3) The value you want to return is NOT available yet when `get_post()` returns.    So, see the question yours has been marked a duplicate of for solutions.  You will need to either return a promise which you resolve with the proper value or you will need to accept a callback that you can call with the final value.

Answer (score 0):

`simple_get` is an async function, it means your code goes through `console.log()` before it actually receives any response